# Can't get psycopg2 to connect to a postgresql server, locally

Tags: python, postgresql, server, localhost, psycopg2

I can't connect though a python script using psycopg2 to a postgresql server. I want to connect locally, through localhost. I can create a new server in the pgAdmin4 using the following parameters:

```
dbname=my-database
username=postgres
password=1234
host=localhost
port=5423
```

Here's the python code that doesn't work:

```
import psycopg2 as psy

def create_table():
    conn = psy.connect(dbname="testdatabase", user="postgres", password="1234", host="localhost", port="5423")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store(item TEXT, quantity INTEGER, price REAL)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def insert(item, quantity, price):
    conn = psy.connect(dbname="testdatabase", user="postgres", password="1234", host="localhost", port="5423")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO store VALUES(%s, %s, %s)", (item, quantity, price))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def view():
    conn = psy.connect("dbname='testdatabase' user='postgres' password='1234' host='localhost' port='5423'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM store")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

def delete(item):
    conn = psy.connect("dbname='testdatabase' user='postgres' password='1234' host='localhost' port='5423'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM store WHERE item=(?)", (item,)) #need comma after when one item
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def update(item, price, quantity):
    conn = psy.connect("dbname='testdatabase' user='postgres' password='1234' host='localhost' port='5423'")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE store SET quantity=?, price=? WHERE item=?", (quantity, price, item))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

create_table()
insert("Golf stuff", 5, 2.65)
```

Here's my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "psycopg.py", line 39, in <module>
    create_table()
  File "psycopg.py", line 4, in create_table
    conn = psy.connect("dbname=testdatabase user=postgres password=1234 host=localhost port=5423")
  File "C:\Users\Andy Renz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5423?
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5423?
```

I've looked through many forums and tinkered with various files. Here's their status=>

**pg-hba:**

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

**postgresql (the relevant bits):**

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
```

**My *hosts* file:**

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    ::1/        localhost
    127.0.0.1/  localhost
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm pretty lost

Comment: Have you verified that postgresql is actually running?

Comment: I can start a server that runs within pgAdmin4 if that's what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Super super simple.

I wrote:

```
port=5423
```

It should be:

```
port=5432
```

Classic typo sending me to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Thanks everyone who looked at my question!